# Bind attribute class in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I see `{{bindAttr class="isEnabled:enabled:disabled"}}` on emberjs.com. It will apply enabled class for true, otherwise is disabled with attribute class. But when I try it in jsfiddle.net, it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ember/59/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that jsfiddle is using old version emberjs 0.9.5.
Update it to the latest version and the code will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ember/61/

Answer (score 2):

You are using Ember.js `v0.9.5` where this feature has been introduced in `v1.0.0pre`. Here's a working example using this latest release: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/E69Gv/.